# window 7 freezes after automatic update on Dec 30 2012

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze

I am using windows 7 on 64 bit toshiba machine from more than a year. My machine is down from 4 days. What I suspect is "problem caused by windows auto update ran on 30th Dec morning.

FYI: I am using dual os, win and ubuntu. I have ubuntu and that is working fine, only windows has got issue.

Symptoms:
1. Login into windows, its taking time. desktop comes, gadgets doesn't appear. It keeps on looking for wireless connection.
2. when press windows start key or do anything task bar freezes.
3. when task bar freezes, the time display in lower right corner freezes too.
4. even pressing alt+ctrl+del , never works and i was forced to hard boot it.

What i did to fix it.
1. Restarted in safe mode, disabled startup items, like antivirus, skype and few other items.
no use, the is still same.

2. tried to restore windows from a restore point on 23rd Dec 2012, that too didn't work, it says couldn't recover.

I suspect this to be a windows automatic update issue.

Any guesses or solution fix this issue.

Comment: 1) Try and disable the wireless connection (from the hotkey). 2) Have you waited for the "freeze" to recover, for some time ?

Comment: I did disable the wifi and then tried too, it didn't help. I gave it enough to recover from freeze, it didn't even after 15 minutes. yes it comes back but that is very slow. last night it took me 30 minuetes to disbale startup items using msconfig and restart but that didn't help too. Also I am using KasperSky antivirus and definition may be 1-2 days old.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall the recent update and see if it fixes your issue. Here is a link which details the steps :[Remove Recent Windows Update](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/Troubleshoot-problems-with-removing-updates)

Comment: I'll not able to navigate to screen where I can remove the updates, its too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Kaspersky? This is known to cause it:

http://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?showtopic=251937

Several users reported that removing KIS fixed the slowness.

Comment: Yes, I am using kasperkey internet security.my version is internet security 2012 and the forum talks about 2013. This may be an issue, however I did try to start machine by removing it from startup list using msconfig.I'll try it once again.

Comment: Thanks, It looks like issue is with kaspersky only. From safe mode I did window restore to my second last restore point, restore completed successfully. How can I disable/uninstall it? from safe its not allowed and from normal mode, it remains in hanged state. Any suggestions?

Comment: use this tool: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/tips/jsi-tip-9233-safemsi-exe-freeware-starts-windows-installer-in-safe-mode- it activates the Windows Installer service for safe mode. Now you can remove Kaspersky.

Comment: Hi magicandre1981, I tried this, it didn't allow me to download this file in safe mode. Also I noticed that the file is preety old, not sure if that will work on Windows 7.

Comment: @sudmong the file still works

Comment: Hi, i did try that. Also used the remove tool provided by the kaspersky technical support team. later I removed few more software.But of no use, it just takes time and freezes, cpu usgae 0%, memory usage 20%, i have 6 gb of RAM. stopped using windows for now, using ubuntu that i had in dual boot. i m simply clueless.